# Searching a range to see if range "contains" a value

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, excel-2013

I have a huge spreadsheet that I am trying to make more efficient for searching, etc. instead of just using Ctrl+F.

What I would like to accomplish is look in column G to see if a value is contained in that column and if true, reply with the corresponding row value in column U.  Notice that the lookup range is not column A, so VLOOKUP would not work.

(Actually Ideally I would like to return both G and U, concatenated together, but I don't know if that's possible)

Here is a simplified example (its school program codes)

Column G (program code - this is what I want to search for)
PHD-PPA-XX
PHD-PPA-CJPY
PHD-PPA-PBAD
PHD-PPA-PBPY

Column U (program name - overly simplified for this example)
PhD Program 1
PhD Program 2
PhD Program 3
PhD Program 4

I would like to search in column G to see if the program code CONTAINS "PBPY" and if it does the return the program name "PhD Program 4"

My ideal scenario would be the return result would concatenate the two into "PHD-PPA-PBPY - PhD Program 4"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you considered using the range.find metod? it retuns a range object so if you use

`code
With Worksheets(1).Range("G:G") 
    Set c = .Find("What you want to find", lookin:=xlValues) 
end with
`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

- `=INDEX(G1:G4,MATCH("*PBPY",G1:G4,0))&" -
  "&INDEX(U1:U4,MATCH("*PBPY",G1:G4,0))`

By the way, the problem with VLookup is not so much that your lookup value is not in column A, since column G is to the left of column U. The problem lies with looking up a partial string and therefore needing to use a wildcard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since I want to type the search value in each time, how would I reference a cell vs. "*PBPY" as the search value?

Comment: I tried this, but it returned the value associated with "A1", instead of the cell A1 value...if that makes sense  =INDEX(G1:G4,MATCH("*A1",G1:G4,0))&" -
"&INDEX(U1:U4,MATCH("*A1",G1:G4,0))

Comment: `=INDEX(G1:G4,MATCH(A1,G1:G4,0))&" - "&INDEX(U1:U4,MATCH(A1,G1:G4,0))` works. You don't need the double quotes before and after the cell reference. Excel knows that *PBPY entered in cell A1 is text.

Comment: If you don't want to type the asterisk each time then use: `=INDEX(G1:G4,MATCH("*"&A1,G1:G4,0))&" - "&INDEX(U1:U4,MATCH("*"&A1,G1:G4,0))` and just type PBPY in cell A1

Comment: Sorry...one more question/caveat to this.  Since I am searching program codes, there maybe several codes that will return if I search for say "SCI" in the code.  There maybe 4 results.  Is there a way to return all of these results, in differing cells in column B?  Ideally answer 1, would be in B1, and answer 2 would be in B2, etc. for however many results there are for the searched value.

Comment: No need to apologize, just open a staff position for me (J/K). This is an array formula, so after you paste this to B1, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`. The formula is `=IFERROR(INDEX(G$1:G$10,SMALL(IF(G$1:G$10=A$1,ROW(G$1:G$10)),ROWS(B$1:B1)))&" - "&INDEX(U$1:U$10,SMALL(IF(G$1:G$10=A$1,ROW(G$1:G$10)),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")` There is a drawback in that the small function does not ,as of ver. 2010, allow the use of a wildcard character, so you will have to type in the entire "program code". My suggestion would be to set up Data Validation for A1 to make sure the program code entered is correctly.

Comment: After you have entered the formula in B1 and while it is still selected pull the fill handle to B4, or further if desired.